# Is there any potential problem if i set the affinity of threads created by kernel through `cpuset(7)`?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, scheduler, scheduling

`Cpuset(7)` could set the affinity of user processes indeed.

But ,is there any potential problem if i set the affinity of threads created by kernel?

Comment: Yes, else everyone would be doing it.

Comment: What potential problems are? Decrease the the whole system output?

Comment: Self DoS is one possibility that comes to my mind. I recommend to watch the presentation about `printk()` in the kernel by Steven Rostedt. He explains what problems he encountered with something similar (it's all around `console_lock()` in his presentation, but you may see similarities with your case).